# How to write Kotlin unit test to test a function internally calling other functions

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit5, mockk

I'm new Kotlin and facing issue while writing Kotlin Junit test, unable to go inside if condition!

```
    override fun process(message: String) {
    try {
        logger.info("(invFileTransformer) Process inventory processor evaluation started...")
        val sqsPayloadInfo = UtilityFunctions.sqsQPayloadExtractor(message)
        val inventoryInfo = UtilityFunctions.extractInventoryType(sqsPayloadInfo[0])
        if (!inventoryInfo.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            transformerProcessService.startProcess(
                sqsPayloadInfo[0],
                inventoryInfo[0],
                inventoryInfo[1],
                sqsPayloadInfo[1]
            )
        } else {
            logger.info("(invFileTransformer) Incorrect inventory directory path!")
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.message
        logger.info("(invFileTransformer) Process inventory processor evaluation error: $ex.message")
    }
}
```

Please help or share a helpful link, Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your exact issue - you're unsure how to test the code within the if-block, as inventoryInfo is always null or empty in the unit test? Or you got the error "unable to go inside if condition" from Junit?

Comment: Hi @DJ_Polly, I called "verify { processorSpy.process(data) }" BUT it never cover IF ELSE because 'sqsQPayloadExtractor' 'extractInventoryType' empty why??. I'm unable to understand pls let me know if you have idea, sure..

Comment: Are you testing this `process` method independently? If yes, where is the call to `process` that you are verifying as per above comment? share your test code.

Comment: We have no idea why your variables are coming back empty because we don't know anything about your code. That's kinda the point of tests - you write something like this that should work, and when it fails you go find out why and fix it!

Comment: Also this isn't really a *unit test*, because you're not just testing `process` here - you're also relying on `UtilityFunctions.sqsQPayloadExtractor` and `extractInventoryType` to work, so really you're testing those too, instead of just one thing. Because they're hardcoded references, instead of a dependency you pass in (which you could mock to provide "ideal" behaviour for the test) it means you can't test `process` in isolation. It seems like your problem is with those `UtilityFunctions` methods anyway - `process` might be fine, you can't tell from this test because they're breaking it

Comment: Exactly. What are those other two functions doing? Also, what `message` are you passing into your test? Please share test code and UtilityFunctions.